# "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module" from webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to start using [webpack](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto) to bundle and minify my JS files, but I'm having a problem getting started.

Right now I am just including my raw JS in my HTML like this:

```
<script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I have made a file in the `js` directory called `webpack.config.json`, which contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./jquery.min.js', './jquery.dataTables.min.js', './dataTables.bootstrap.min.js', './d3.v3.min.js', './d3.tip.v0.6.3.js', './index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: './main.js'
  }
};
```

Now when I switch to the `js` directory, and run `webpack`, I see the following errors:

```
WARNING in ./main.js from UglifyJs
Condition always true [./d3.v3.min.js:5,23414]
Condition always true [./dataTables.bootstrap.min.js:5,13]
Condition always true [./jquery.dataTables.min.js:5,13]

ERROR in ./jquery.dataTables.min.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in /myapp/app/js
 @ ./jquery.dataTables.min.js 5:52-111

ERROR in ./dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in /myapp/app/js
 @ ./dataTables.bootstrap.min.js 5:52-128

ERROR in ./dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'datatables.net' in /myapp/app/js
 @ ./dataTables.bootstrap.min.js 5:52-128
```

I don't fully understand this, because the dependencies were always OK before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldnt you want your entry to be a single `index.js` file that `requires` in your dependencies?

Comment: I'd expect much more descriptive question title from a 10k user.

Comment: @TomášZato I've edited the question title, apologies!

Comment: @Daniel_L I have no idea, I'm just trying to follow the [webpack documentation](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto) to the best of my ability.

Comment: @Richard even in that guide he's not specifying an array of entry points. you should post your entire project structure as well, since that's usually necessary info in webpack debug posts.

Comment: webpack isn't really meant for concatenating scripts, but for using modules, normally you would use jQuery from NPM etc and then expose the $ etc if required. Because you are using a module bundling system, bootstrap is most likely detecting this, it is possible to expose globals to other modules as modules, by using the externals options.  eg.  `externals: { "jquery": "jQuery" }`

Comment: @Keith thanks. What would you recommend instead for concatenating scripts? My project really isn't complex, it's just a small index file with some external vendor files.

Comment: First port of call see if there are NPM versions eg.  the  jquery datatables -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables  D3 -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3  etc, what you normally do is then NPM install these, then you can just do require('d3'); etc.

Comment: @Keith thanks! And would I then use some system to compile them?

Comment: @Richard  That's what webpack will do for you, the nice thing then is you can use webpack with the -p option for production mode, and webpack -d for development mode, and it will use sourcemaps, or minification etc automatically for you.